# Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier. (when using a token)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, token, jobs

I have this code in a job step, the stored procedure runs fine, the issue is with the getting of the job name.

```
declare @jobName varchar(100)

set @jobName = (select name from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))')

EXEC spSendSuccessEmail @jobName
```

Am I missing anything?

All I'm trying to do is pass the job id that the step is in to the stored procedure.

Comment: What does `'$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))'` get resolved to? Maybe try logging that to a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearly using a varchar where a uniqueidentifier is expected.  Ideally you want to fix the typing, but a cast will do the trick too.
If the sp is expecting a uniqueidentifier try casting @jobName to uniqueidentifier before executing sp

Comment: That won't work. You can't `CAST` inline in an `exec`. Also if the implicit cast to unique identifier fails there must be something wrong with the value that an explicit cast won't solve. [The OP is trying to use a SQL Agent macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx)

Comment: Ok, edited answer, then cast at "set @ jobname = CAST(xxx AS unique identifier).  I mentioned in my answer this is a band-aid, a better solution would be to type @jobName as uniqueidentifier.

Comment: It isn't the `EXEC` that is even causing the problem. It is the `where job_id = '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))'`

Comment: the issue is with what @MartinSmith said. i got passed this by setting the job id to what it actually is but i would prefer doing the right way and using the token because now i have to manually change the id for each of the jobs i wanna do this with.

Comment: @Testifier - Damien_The_Unbeliever posted a correct answer but deleted it for some reason. `set @jobName = (select name from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID))))` ought to work as `JOBID` is returned in binary format `0x...`

Comment: How is this any different than what I said almost an hour ago?  CAST/CONVERT the varchar to uniqueidentifier.  This is not complicated...

Comment: You suggested casting the job **name** to `uniqueidentifier` in an irrelevant part of the code and using invalid syntax. Additionally casting on its own is not sufficient and would just give the same error. the OP needs `ESCAPE_NONE` instead of `ESCAPE_SQUOTE` (in which case `select name from msdb..sysjobs where job_id = $(ESCAPE_NONE(JOBID))` would also work fine with the implicit cast.

Comment: I'm hoping that Damien undeletes their answer (or at least explains the motivation for deleting it) as they got there first.